# In Django, restrict user view using class based views

Tags: django

I have this url pattern:

```
path("user/<int:pk>", MyAccountView.as_view(), name='my_account'),
```

And this view:

```
class MyAccountView(DetailView):

    model = CustomUser
```

When the user is logged Django redirect to that URL.

The problem is that any user can access other users.

For example, if the logged user has pk 25, he can access the view of user with pk 26 by writing in the browser url box:

```
localhost:8000/user/26
```

I want that each user can access to his user page only, so if user with pk 25 try to access the url with pk 26, the access should be denied.

Can you point me in some direction of how this is done? The Django documentation is very confusing in this respect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `get` method of `DetailView`

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyAccountView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = CustomUser

    def get(self, request, pk):
        if request.user.pk != pk:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. The Django doc says I should use Mixins like UserPassesTestMixin and other stuff like that. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Easy !

1. First change the view path from `user/<int:pk>/` to `user/`
2. Link the view to the `current user`, `DetailView` won't work because it heavily relies on either `pk` or `slug` and we won't be using none of them, so you'll have to write a new view. (Example using `FBV` because i do not use `CBV`)

```
# views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# redirects to login page if the user is not authenticated
@login_required(login_url='/example url you want redirect/') 
def get_user_profile(request):
    context = dict(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

And that's it, any user visiting `/user/` will only see their account/profile.